# Page show - Index of - instead of content

Tags: php, html

I have a site running just fine, but since shortly my support page stopped working. Whenever I link to it, it shows me a blank page with the text `index of /support` instead of the content that should be loaded.

My index.php is as followed

```
<?php
    require_once ('inc/db/dbControl.php');
    require_once ('inc/db/functionControl.php');        
    include_once ("inc/page/header.php");
    include_once ("inc/elements/body.php");
    if (!empty($_GET['p'])){
        if($_GET['p'] == "admin"){
        }else{
            include_once ("inc/page/navigation.html");
        }
    }else{
        include_once ("inc/page/navigation.html");
    }
    include_once ("inc/page/pagepicker.php"); 
    if (!empty($_GET['p'])){
        if($_GET['p'] == "admin"){  
        }else{
            include_once ("inc/page/footer.html");
        }
    }else{
        include_once ("inc/page/footer.html");
    }
    include_once ("inc/elements/body_close.php");
    include_once ("inc/page/scripts.php");
?>
```

In my `index.php` is a pagepicker, that runs as followed

```
if (!empty($_GET['p'])){
    $pages_dir = 'inc/content';
    $pages = scandir($pages_dir, 0);
    unset($pages[0], $pages[1]);

    $p = $_GET['p'];

    if(in_array($p.'.inc.php', $pages)){
        include($pages_dir.'/'.$p.'.inc.php');  
    }
    else
    {
            echo '<p>404 Page not found. Deze website is momenteel in aanbouw. Kom later nog eens terug of neem contact met ons op via <a href="mailto:info@jellyfishwebdesign.nl">info@jellyfishwebdesign.nl</a></p>';
    }
}else{
    include('inc/content/home.inc.php');
}
```

It works for every page, except for the support page which contains the following.

```
<?php
    include_once ("inc/elements/support_front.html");
    include_once ("inc/elements/video.php");
    echo '<section class="content_web">';
        include_once  ("inc/elements/support_algemeen.html");
    echo '</section>';
?>
```

Since there is no folder called support (this is done via rewritting URL), I have no clue what is going on here.

The htacces file is this

```
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)$ index.php?p=$1 [L]
    RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$  index.php?p=$1&t=$2 [L]
```

For the example online, surft to [the website](http://jellyfishwebdesign.nl/home) and hit the support icons. How can I solve this?

**edit**

When I check console, it tries to load the page but in 2 instances. Once as jellyfishwebdesign/support and once as jellyfishwebdesign/support/ ... the last one is the one that gets accepted, the other gives me in the headers this:

```
Remote Address: ------- blanked
Request URL:http://jellyfishwebdesign.nl/support
Request Method:GET
Status Code:301 Moved Permanently (from cache)
Request Headers
Provisional headers are shown
Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Referer:http://jellyfishwebdesign.nl/home
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36
Response Headers
Content-Length:245
Content-Type:text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
Date:Sun, 14 Dec 2014 21:47:45 GMT
Location:http://jellyfishwebdesign.nl/support/
Server:Apache/2.2.27 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.27 OpenSSL/1.0.1e-fips mod_bwlimited/1.4
```

Comment: its not blank, it shows me a `page with the text index of /support` there is no error in console or what so ever. I checked that

Comment: My bad - has anything changed recently? Updates etc? Do other PHP files work?

Comment: The rest works fine. You can check the site itself. All works, from blog to websites, the about us section and contact, they all run fine. Its just this page.

Comment: On a side note, empty conditionals are not really good you have `if($_GET['p'] == "admin"){ }else{ include...}` - If you don't do something with a conditional, but do on an else, then just reverse the initial `if` condition to do whatever would happen on the else. So instead, do this `if($_GET['p'] != "admin"){ include...}`

Comment: That text indicates that you have a `/support` directory in your webroot. Since your rewrite rules won't run if the request matches a directory, it loads the directory instead.

Comment: It took indeed some searching in the webfolder, but yes, I noticed a co-worker has created two subfolders within my root, without my knowledge (I was the only one working on this project), one of them indeed called `support` (checked the server logs after your comment to be sure). Thanks for the suggestion! Problem solved!